# Tikz. Radial shading of a disk

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I'm trying to create a ball similar to the image

[image: this effect]

So I've used the following tikz code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepgflibrary {shadings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[shading=radial, outer color=cyan!80!black, inner color = white] (0, 0) circle (.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the resulting image

[image]

is very far from the goal, and I do not find any hint on how to control the inner intense white area size.

Answer (score 7):

How about some testing of color blend values ​​and some randomly drawn lines.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (-0.7,-0.7) rectangle ++(1.4,1.4);
            \shade[inner color=cyan!90!black, outer color=black!80!cyan] (0,0) circle (1);
            \shade[inner color=cyan!100!white, outer color=cyan!55!black] (0,0) circle (0.5);
            \shade[inner color=white, outer color=cyan!77!black] (0,0) circle (0.25);
            \foreach \k in {1,...,30}{\draw[white,opacity=rnd*0.5,=3pt] (0,0) -- ++(rnd*360:2);}
            \foreach \k in {1,...,30}{\draw[white,opacity=rnd*0.5,=3pt] (rnd*360:1) -- (rnd*360:1);}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}]
            \clip (-.7,-.7) rectangle (.7,.7);
            \fill[black](-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
            \fill[inner color=yellow,outer color=black] (0,0) circle (1);
            \path[inner color=white,outer color=yellow!50!black] (0,0) circle (.5);
            \foreach \k in {1,...,30}{\draw[white,opacity=rnd*0.5,=3pt] (0,0) -- ++(rnd*360:2);}
            \foreach \k in {1,...,30}{\draw[white,opacity=rnd*0.5,=3pt] (rnd*360:1) -- (rnd*360:1);}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I did not care for lines at all. But you have achieved a very nice result.